# C++ Linked List list_copy_front function confusion

Tags: c++, linked-list, copy, nodes

I've been struggling with this last function (list_copy_front). The function is for a linked list, it is supposed to return the value of the head pointer for a new list that contains copies of the first n nodes that the source pointer points to. Also if there is less than n nodes in the source then just copy all. Currently, when I run it as is I get a nasty Segmentation Fault SIGSEGV error. The debugger says the error happens at "Node *cursor = source_ptr-> link; Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Here is some relevant info,

```
struct Node
{
    typedef int Item;
    Item data;
    Node *link;
};

void list_tail_attach(Node*& head_ptr, const Node::Item& entry);
Node* list_copy_front(Node* source_ptr, size_t n);

void list_tail_attach(Node*& head_ptr, const Node::Item& entry)
{
    Node *last = new Node;

    last->data = entry;
    last->link = NULL;

    if(head_ptr == NULL)
    {
        head_ptr = last;
    }
    else
    {
        Node *temp = new Node;
        temp = head_ptr;
        while(temp->link != NULL)
        {
            temp = temp->link;
        }
        temp->link = last;
    }
}

Node* list_copy_front(Node* source_ptr, size_t n)
{
    Node *new_head_ptr = new Node;
    Node *cursor = source_ptr->link;
    size_t i = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        list_tail_attach(new_head_ptr, cursor->data);
        cursor = cursor->link;
    }
    return new_head_ptr;
}
```

Here's the Main test for the function

```
int test4()
{
    Node* list = NULL; // an empty list
    Node* copy = NULL;
    copy = list_copy_front(list, 3);
    if(copy != NULL)
    {
        cout << "list_copy_front function doesn't work for copying empty list\n";
        return 0;
    }
    for(int i = 1; i <= 4; i++)
        list_tail_attach(list, i);
    // list contains 1, 2, 3, 4

    copy = list_copy_front(list, 3);
    if(list_length(copy) != 3 || copy->data != 1 || copy->link->data != 2 || copy->link->link->data != 3 )
    {
        cout << "list_copy_front function doesn't work\n";
        return 0;
    }

    copy->link->data = 100;
    if(list->link->data == 100)
    {
        cout << "list_copy_front function doesn't work.\n";
        return 0;
    }
    list_clear(copy);
    copy = list_copy_front(list, 6);
    if(list_length(copy) != 4)
    {
        cout << "list_copy_front function doesn't work\n";
        return 0;
    }

    cout << "list_copy_front passes the test\n";

    list_clear(list);
    for(int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
        list_head_insert(list, i);
    // list contains 3, 2, 1

    list_copy(list, copy);
    if(list_length(copy) != 3 || copy->data != 3 || copy->link->data != 2 || copy->link->link->data != 1 )
    {
        cout << "list_copy function doesn't work\n";
        return 0;
    }

    cout << "list_copy function passes the test\n";

    return 2;

}
```

Edit 3
So far here's what I'm working with I appreciate the comments so far it's just not quite working out. Which is probably my fault for not explaining better.

```
void list_tail_attach(Node*& head_ptr, const Node::Item& entry)
{
    Node *last = new Node;  // Creates new Node
    last->data = entry; // Points last to data
    last->link = NULL;

    if(last == NULL)
    {
        return;
    }

    if(head_ptr == NULL)
    {
        head_ptr = last;
    }
    else
    {
        Node *temp = head_ptr;
        while(temp->link != NULL)
        {
            temp = temp->link;
        }
        temp->link = last;
    }
}


Node* list_copy_front(Node* source_ptr, size_t n)
{
    if(source_ptr == NULL)
    {
       return NULL;
    }
    Node *new_head_ptr = new Node;
    Node *cursor = source_ptr;

    size_t i = 0;

    while(cursor!= NULL && i < n)
    {
        list_tail_attach(new_head_ptr, cursor->data);
        cursor = cursor->link;
        i++;
    }

    return new_head_ptr;
}
```

I am not allowed to change the way the function takes it's input so, that's why I left Node *last.
I left  list_tail_attach(new_head_ptr, cursor->data) because without it I get an invalid conversion error. However when I run the above code I still receive an SIGSEGV error for while(temp->link != NULL) in list_tail_attach and on list_tail_attach(new_head_ptr, cursor->data); in list_copy_front.

Thank you if you are able to comment further

Comment: can you attach the `main` program, seems that `source_ptr` is not `null` but `source_ptr->link` is `null`

Comment: I've got that added in there

Comment: Isn't this `copy = list_copy_front(list, 3);` will cause error?

Comment: I don't believe so, could you explain why you think that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My professor helped me out with the correct solution. For anyone who views this in the future...

```
Node* list_copy_front(Node* source_ptr, size_t n)
{
    if(source_ptr == NULL)  // Takes care of NULL case
    {
       return NULL;
    }
    Node *new_head_ptr = NULL;  // Creates new head and ensures NULL
    Node *cursor = source_ptr;  // Sets temp Node = to source

    size_t i = 0;   // Initializes temp variable

    while(cursor!= NULL && i < n)   // Loop that continues while n is bigger than i and it is not NULL
    {
        list_tail_attach(new_head_ptr, cursor->data);
        cursor = cursor->link;  // Attaches to new list
        i++;    // Increases count
    }
    return new_head_ptr;
}
```

The line that needed to be changed was
Node * new_head_ptr = new Node;
to
Node * new_head_ptr = NULL;

Answer (score 0):

The first test case

```
Node* list = NULL; // an empty list
Node* copy = NULL;
copy = list_copy_front(list, 3);
```

gives Node* source_ptr == NULL and expects your function to handle it gracefully.
The function code soon tries to dereference NULL

```
Node *cursor = source_ptr->link;
```

The result is a segfault.

Comment: @AchmadJP your comment has the same info, sooner than my answer. Why not make it an answer? It could be accepted as the faster answer.

Comment: So to fix this without changing the test function. I need to adjust the list_copy_function in order to handle a NULL case?

Comment: That is my understanding of your problem, yes.

Answer (score 0):

First is `list_tail_attach`, this function I assumed to be attaching an existing `Node` into a linked list. If the linked list is `null` then the `Node` become the `head`

```
void list_tail_attach(Node *& head_ptr, Node *& entry)
{
    if (entry == NULL) {
        return;
    }
    if (head_ptr == NULL)
    {
        head_ptr = entry;
    }
    else
    {
        Node *temp = head_ptr;
        while (temp->link != NULL)
        {
            temp = temp->link;
        }
        temp->link = entry;
    }
}
```

I changed the `entry` into a reference to a pointer to made it easier.

Ok, now move on to the `list_copy_front`

```
Node * list_copy_front(Node* source_ptr, size_t n)
{
    if (source_ptr == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }
    Node * new_head_ptr = new Node;
    Node * cursor = source_ptr;

    size_t i = 0;

    while(cursor != NULL && i < n){
        list_tail_attach(new_head_ptr, cursor);
        cursor = cursor->link;
        i++;
    }

    return new_head_ptr;
}
```

You have to guard the `source_ptr` in case it is `null`.

To attach a new `Node`

```
for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
    Node * tmp = new Node();
    tmp->data = x;
    tmp->link = NULL;
    list_tail_attach(list, tmp);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the information, I don't understand where this for loop would be placed. I've also added info to my post.